# Select multiple tabs and close

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

In Chrome, I can <kbd>shift</kbd>+click to automatically select all tabs in between the tab I'm on and the tab I click on, and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close them. Is there any way I can achieve this with Firefox?

Comment: Related bug report / feature request: [1458007 - \[meta\] Allow multiselect operations on tabs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1458007)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox Quantum - select multiple tabs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1270888/firefox-quantum-select-multiple-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there is nothing like this for Firefox like there is for Chrome. (Well, there is, but it's so irritating that it's worthless.) Firefox has an add-on where you can customize the shortcut keys, but it doesn't allow you to add new ones. There is also an unofficial add-on extension that gives Firefox that same ability and with 18k votes @ 4/12 stars I say it works.

Here are the two links from Firefox that tell you all the shortcut keys. I personally still use the middle mouse scroll to kill tabs fast.

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mouse-shortcuts-perform-common-tasks